# Inserting an HTML fragment into a WPF FlowDocument

Tags: html, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I'm dynamically building a WPF FlowDocument from a datasource.  One of the data elements is a fragment of HTML - I need to figure out a way to parse that and insert it into my FlowDocument.

I've found [HTMLToXAMLConverter](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx) which will return a XAML representation of the HTML, but I'm still not sure how to best go about instantiating that XAML fragment so I can insert it into my FlowDocument.

Comment: For anybody who doesn't want to deal with FlowDocument : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720946/displaying-html-in-wpf-using-mvvm/61226039#61226039

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered my own question...

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, but had to solve databinding problems as well

Had a convector that created XAML from string and vice-verse.