# How to display HTML help file in WPF

Tags: html, wpf, xaml, html-helper

I have a help file, in HTML format, that I need to display within my MVVM Application in WPF.  I don't want to use anything WinForms related and I don't want any dependency on ActiveX or IE.  Is there not a simple and out-of-the-box way to do this in WPF?  Do I need to go through the hassel of writing converters and other unwanted code?

Comment: check this link. it might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720946/displaying-html-in-wpf-using-mvvm

Comment: Check this [project](http://htmltorichtextbox.codeplex.com/). It's Silverlight libary but you can recompile this in ClassLibrary.